# A particular type of ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

A nonempty subset $A$ of a ring $R$ is termed $\textit{adeal}$ of $R$ if

$(i)$ $a,b\in A$ imply $a+b\in A$;

$(ii)$ $r\in R$ and $a\in A$ imply both $ar\in A$ and $ra\in A$.

Prove that

$(a)$ An adeal $A$ of $R$ is an ideal of $R$ if for each $a\in A$ there is an integer $n\ne 0$, depending upon $a$, such that $na\in aR+Ra$. (This condition is satisfied, in particular, if $R$ ha a multiplicative identity). (why does it depend upon a?)

$(b)$ Whenever $R$ is a commutative ring, the condition in part $(a)$ is a necessary as well as sufficient condition for an adeal to be an ideal. [$Hint$:For any $a\in R$, the set $A=\{na\;|\;n\in\mathbb{Z_+}\}+aR$ is an adeal of $R$; hence, an ideal of $R$].

I find it difficult to solve this exercise, even though I have reflected on it, could someone give me some suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you point out, e.g. by examples, what's the difference between *adeal* and *ideal*?

Comment: What is your definition of an ideal if not this? This is a two-sided ideal in the non-commutative case and you would drop one of the conditions on the product $ar$ or $ra$ to be in $A$ to get a left or right ideal?

Comment: @BerciA definition of ideal is $(ii)$ with the addition that $a-b\in Ideal$

Comment: Where did the exercise come from, incidentally?

Comment: @ rschwiebDavid Burton A first course in rings and ideals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, it's helpful to write down the definition of an ideal, as defined by this book:

A nonempty subset $A$ of a ring $R$ is an $\textit{ideal}$ of $R$ if

$(i)$ $a,b\in A$ imply $a-b\in A$;

$(ii)$ $r\in R$ and $a\in A$ imply both $ar\in A$ and $ra\in A$.

If $A$ is an adeal, then to show that $A$ is in fact an ideal, then it suffices to show that if $a \in A$ then $-a \in A$. In fact, it suffices to show that if $a \in A$ then there exists $m \geq 1$ such that $-ma \in A$: if $m = 1$ we're done, and if $m > 1$ then $(m-1)a + -ma = -a \in A$.

So let $a \in A$, and assume that the condition in part (a) of the question holds, so there exists $n > 0 \in \Bbb N$ and $r, s \in R$ such that $na = ra + as$. Then $-na = -ra + a(-s) \in A$, so we're done.

It should be pointed out that $na$, by definition, equals $a + a + \cdots + a$, where there are $n$ terms in the sum; $n$ is not an element of $R$ if $R$ does not have a multiplicative identity. In the above proof, you should check each statement using the definition of $na$, since there are several things that are less obvious than they look.

For part (b), it's not true as stated. Consider $R = \Bbb Z$ with the trivial multiplication $ab = 0$ for all $a, b$ (which is obviously commutative), so for any $a$, $aR + Ra = 0$, so the condition $na \in aR + Ra$ can never hold unless $na = 0$ for some $a$, which requires $a = 0$. But the whole of $R$ is an adeal of $R$ which is also an ideal of $R$, which if (b) was true would imply the condition held for all elements of $R$.